# PropertyDeclarationSyntax and MethodDeclarationSyntax have a common property but don't inherit from the same class or implement the same interface

Tags: c#

In C# syntax analysis, the `PropertyDeclarationSyntax` and `MethodDeclarationSyntax` both have an `Identifier` property. However, they both inherit from `CSharpSyntaxNode` which does not.

I'd like to write a method that can take a `CompilationUnitSyntax` object, extract all `PropertyDeclarationSyntax` or `MethodDeclarationSyntax` objects from it and populate a list with their names. Here's what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{

    static List<string> GrabNames(CompilationUnitSyntax root)
    {
        List<MethodDeclarationSyntax> methods = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().ToList();
        List<string> methodNames = new List<string>();

        foreach (MethodDeclarationSyntax method in methods)
        {
            methodNames.Add(method.Identifier.Text);
        }

        return methodNames;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileContainingCode = "test.cs"; // file path
        string CodeAsText = File.ReadAllText(fileContainingCode);
        SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(CodeAsText);
        CompilationUnitSyntax root = tree.GetCompilationUnitRoot();

        List<string> names = GrabNames(root);
}
```

I can think of one ugly solution, namely to add a string parameter called `NodeTypeAsString` and based on its value have two branches of an `if` statement do the exact same thing, but then on different types.

However, I'm thinking there has got to be a better/cleaner way. How can I achieve this without duplicating too much code?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a clean OOP-style solution to this problem.

I suggest to use the following function:

```cs
string GetIdentifier(SyntaxNode node) => switch node {
    PropertyDeclarationSyntax p => p.Identifier,
    MethodDeclarationSyntax m => m.Identifier,
    _ => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Use it like so:

```cs
var names = root
    .DescendantNodes()
    .Where(n => n.IsKind(SyntaxKind.PropertyDeclaration)
             || n.IsKind(SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration))
    .Select(GetIdentifier)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: That's exactly the "ugly" solution I wanted to avoid, which I mentioned in my OP. What if I have 100 `SyntaxKind`s? I'd have to pile them all up in both `GetIdentifier` and its call. Pretty horrible.

Comment: @user32882 Well do you have a 100 `SyntaxKind`s? If not then I wouldn't worry at all. If yes then you could use reflection to check if the provided type has an `Identifier` property.