# Getting the AST node that an attribute refers to in C# using Roslyn

Tags: c#, abstract-syntax-tree, roslyn

Is it possible to get the property that an attribute refers to using Roslyn syntax analysis? I was able to get the attribute name as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using System.Linq;

namespace Project1
{
   internal class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         string sourceCode = File.ReadAllText("TestAttributes.cs");
         SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceCode);
         CompilationUnitSyntax root = tree.GetCompilationUnitRoot();
         AttributeListSyntax node = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<AttributeListSyntax>().First();
         IdentifierNameSyntax identifierName  = node.Attributes[0].Name as IdentifierNameSyntax;
         Console.WriteLine(identifierName.Identifier.Text);
      }
   }
}
```

With `TestAttributes.cs` containing the following:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Project1
{
   public class Person
   {
      [Range(18, 120, ErrorMessage = "Age must be between 18 and 120")]
      public int Age { get; set; }
   }
}
```

However, in this case I'd like to do either of the following:

- Get the node representing the attribute `range` from the node representing the property `Age`
- Get the node representing the property `Age` from the node representing the attribute `range`

Is there any way to do this with the Roslyn syntax analysis API? I'd like to avoid semantic analysis if possible.

## Edit

Here's what I tried after @Selvin's comment:

```
namespace Project1
{
   internal class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         string sourceCode = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\Amine.Aboufirass\\Desktop\\TEMP\\user-story-425155\\syntax-analysis\\Project1\\TestAttributes.cs");
         SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceCode);
         CompilationUnitSyntax root = tree.GetCompilationUnitRoot();
         AttributeListSyntax node = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<AttributeListSyntax>().First();
         IdentifierNameSyntax identifierName  = node.Attributes[0].Name as IdentifierNameSyntax;
         IdentifierNameSyntax correspondingIdentifierName = node.Parent as IdentifierNameSyntax;

         Console.WriteLine(identifierName.Identifier.Text);
         Console.WriteLine(correspondingIdentifierName.Identifier.Text);
      }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm now getting a runtime error.

Comment: Attribute's parent is propertie's and parent of property is class ....

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my OP. I meant to say the how to get the *property* that the attribute refers to, Edited.

Comment: again, you have already `node` which is attribute... `node.Parent` is property `Age` ... if you would have `Age`'s `PropertyDeclarationSyntax` some element of  node of type `AttributeListSyntax` would be again attribute ... what is the definitive goal?

Comment: Ok I tried something based on your suggestion. Please see original post.

Comment: Node pareent would be `PropertyDeclarationSyntax` not `IdentifierNameSyntax` use `((PropertyDeclarationSyntax)node.Parent).Identifier`

Comment: hint: try to post your code to parse [here](https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: Ok yes that worked. But what if my parent node is a class? Then I run into this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401794/propertydeclarationsyntax-and-methoddeclarationsyntax-have-a-common-property-but)